# How does md5DigestAsHex work?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, instance, md5

I cant find out how DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex works.

First I created object through POST request addressed to createUser method

I implemented Cloneable interface in User class to use clone() method.
Then cloned User instance and changed encryptedMessage property in cloned object.
After that, compared two object's encryptedMessage properties, but they are not the same, though all values for encryption are the same.

Condition is always not valid, though it is valid for objects that was created by records in data.sql

```
insert into user(phone_number) values('46564564555');
```

-

```
User user = (User) u.clone();
                        user.setSmsCode(smsCode);
                        encryptMessage(user);
if (u.getEncryptMessage() == null ? user.getEncryptMessage() == null : u.getEncryptMessage().equals(user.getEncryptMessage())) {
                            return Constants.ErrorCodes.SUCCESS;
                        } else {
                            return Constants.ErrorCodes.DO_NOT_MATCH;
```

### }

```
private User encryptMessage(User u) {
        String text = String.valueOf(u.getId()) + String.valueOf(u.getSmsCode()) + u.getPhoneNumber();
        String encrypted = DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(text.getBytes());
        u.setEncryptMessage(encrypted);
        return u;
```

### }

```
   @RequestMapping("/createUser")
   long createUser(@RequestParam(value = "phoneNumber", defaultValue = "") String phoneNumber) {

    Collection<User> collection;
    if (phoneNumber.length() > 10) {
        collection = userRepository.findByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    } else {
        return Constants.ErrorCodes.INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER;
    }

    if (collection != null) {
        if (collection.size() > 0) {
            for (User u : collection) {
                sendSMSCode(u);
                encryptMessage(u);
                userRepository.flush();
                return u.getId();
            }
        } else {
            User u = new User(phoneNumber);
            sendSMSCode(u);
            encryptMessage(u);
            userRepository.saveAndFlush(u);

            return u.getId();
        }
    }
    return Constants.ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
}
```

-

```
@Entity
class User implements Cloneable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id; 
private long smsCode;
@Column(name = "smsCodeDate", columnDefinition = "Decimal(10) default '0'")
private long smsCodeDate;
@Column(name = "encryptedMessage")
private String encryptedMessage;

public User() {
}

public User(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public long getSmsCode() {
    return smsCode;
}

public void setSmsCode(long smsCode) {
    this.smsCode = smsCode;
}

public long getSmsCodeDate() {
    return smsCodeDate;
}

public void setSmsCodeDate(long smsCodeDate) {
    this.smsCodeDate = smsCodeDate;
}

public String getEncryptMessage() {
    return encryptedMessage;
}

public void setEncryptMessage(String encryptMessage) {
    this.encryptedMessage = encryptMessage;
}

@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String md5DigestAsHex(byte[] bytes)

Return a hexadecimal string representation of the MD5 digest of the given  bytes.
```

It calculates the hash of `bytes` and returns a hexadecimal representation of the hash.

BTW: Don't call something that hashes something `encrypt`. Encryption and Hashing are completely different things.

Comment: It exactly answers the question `How does md5DigestAsHex work`. The `md5DigestAsHex`  isn't the problem. You should probably fire up a debugger and inspect what values you have in your objects.

Comment: Is that right, using of clone() to create new object but not reference?

Comment: Clone is supposed to copy the object so it creates a new object and returns a reference to that new object. You should read the docs for `Cloneable` and `Object.clone()` because there are some nasty details.

Comment: One thing I cant reach out, Why object created with sql script works well and object created by POST request does not?

Comment: I can't tell that from here, sorry. Can you post a minimal example? The code you posted doesn't compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in save() and flush().

Firstly it is necessary to call save() to create record in db for id.
Then fill out all data and call flush.

Method encryptMessage got user with id=0, that is why hashes were different

```
User u = new User(phoneNumber);
                userRepository.save(u);
                sendSMSCode(u);
                encryptMessage(u);
                System.out.println(gson.toJson(u));//
                userRepository.flush();
```